# Devices for the generation of polarized light

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, laser, polarization

In many papers dealing with the generation of polarized states of light in imaging applications, Photo Elastic Modulators (PEM) is one of the most chosen devices to modulate the polarization of the incoming laser beam, even if it is a relatively slow device (tens of kHz). Conversely, the use of Electro-Optic Modulator (EOM) is not so spread when dealing with polarized light generation, despite their superior speed (up to MHz). Why one should use the PEM instead of a faster device like the Pockles cell?

Comment: (+1) Good question. I have always assumed that PEMs simply had an advantage in wavelength accessibility, e.g., the optics can be made from ZnSe or whatever. Speed is not always the major factor.

Comment: I've only used EOMs, but I'm pretty sure the answer is that EOMs are the most expensive approach.

Answer (score 0):

In general, companies that sell optical components will help you choose the right one for you. This includes understanding them.

A good starting place is the [RP Photonoics Encyclopedia](https://www.rp-photonics.com/encyclopedia.html) and [Buyer's Guide](https://www.rp-photonics.com/buyersguide.html). These articles may help. [Optical Modulators](https://www.rp-photonics.com/optical_modulators.html), [Electro-optic Modulators](https://www.rp-photonics.com/electro_optic_modulators.html)

Comment: I got your point but I didn't find any motivation about the use of the EOM as generator of polarized states of light. It is often used as optical switch or similar, whereas if the goal is the time-encoding of particular polarization states, the choice is often the PEM.

Comment: You might find a company that sells EOMs and ask to speak to an engineer. They can be a good source of information.